# How to concatenate if template django with variable js

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I would like to know if it is possible to concatenate Django template, I made many attempts but none succeeded as shown below:

```javascript
<script>
function seeDetail(researcher_id) {
    let convert_int_researcher_id = parseInt(researcher_id)

    $('#detailRearcher').empty();
    let element= `
        <br>
        <h2> Detalhes do pesquisador selecionado </h2>
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Artigos</h2>
                    {%for show_list_article in show_list_articles %}
                        {% for article in show_list_article%}
                            {% if article.researcher_id `+ researcher_id+`%}
                                {{article.researcher}}
                                <div class="row">
                                    {{article.title}}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Projetos</h2>
                    {%for show_list_projeto in show_list_projetos %}
                        {% for project in show_list_projeto%}
                            <div class="row">
                                {{project.title}}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    $('#detailRearcher').append(element)
}
```

but when I do this, the following error happens:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '`+' from '`+'
```

If anyone can help me and explain why, I will be totally grateful.

Yes I saw it in the `console.log` and this is actually a string type value and I tried to convert it, but the same error occurs.

Comment: What exactly you want to do when you use `{% if article.researcher_id `+ researcher_id+`%}`

Comment: That isn't valid Django template syntax, but *even if it was* this couldn't work because templates are evaluated on the server, well before the JS can run on the client.

Comment: @scharette 
in this for there are inumerous researcher_id, I'd like to compare with the one in my which I get in function